# Creating a parse function what will count value between strings (costs)

Tags: c#

I am wondering how could I achieve a function that will allow me to count up the service costs.

My data holder.

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
data.Add("01:01 Service cost {get this value} usd.");
data.Add("01:02 Service cost {get this value} usd.");
data.Add("01:03 Service cost {get this value} usd.");
data.Add("01:04 Service cost {get this value} usd.");
var elementMap = ParseData(data);
```

As an output I would like to get the total cost which will be a summary of this elements.

Regexp pseudo

```
00-99:0-99(space)Service cost(space){get this value}(space)usd.
```

Thanks for any tips for achieving it.

Comment: I think splitting the string on a space, then doing a `decimal.Parse` on the 4th item in each array would be easier.

Comment: Can you give examples of the values.

Comment: 1-999999 for instance

Answer (score 4):

> As an output I would like to get the total cost

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
data.Add("01:01 Service cost {get this value} usd.");
data.Add("01:02 Service cost {get this value} usd.");
data.Add("01:03 Service cost {get this value} usd.");
data.Add("01:04 Service cost {get this value} usd.");

var exp = new Regex(@"cost ([$.0-9]+) usd.");
var result = data.Select(d => decimal.Parse(exp.Match(d).Groups[1].Value.Replace("$", ""))).Sum();
```

Alternative based on the suggestion in the question comments to split the string:

```
var result = data.Select(d => decimal.Parse(d.Split(" ".ToCharArray())[3].Replace("$", "")).Sum();
```

Comment: Consider to  accept both dot/comma as you using culture specific parse in the sample...

Comment: @Chimera currency used does not imply locale of document nor what user's customs are to format numbers.

Comment: This text is clearly computer generated. It's fair to believe the values there will use a strict and consistent (regular!) format, rather than something user-entered... but it's easy enough for the OP to adjust the expression to suit his needs. Where you'll have problems is if the computer could generate data in a currency other than USD. Then it's not enough to simply adjust the expression; you also need to parse out which currency and connect to a service to know what exchange rate to use.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this:

```
 var result = data.Select(i =>
 {
     int startIndex = i.IndexOf("Service cost") + 13;
     return double.Parse(i.Substring(startIndex, i.IndexOf("usd.") - startIndex));
 }).ToList();
```

Comment: What does the 13 stands for?

Comment: The second parameter to `string.Substring` is the length of the substring, not the end index.

Comment: @Kavvson It's the number of characters in "Service cost" plus one.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use capture groups within Regex framework.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
Regex regMatch = new Regex("\d\d:\d\d Service cost (?<cost>.*?) usd.")

Match result = regMatch.Match("01:01 Service cost {get this value} usd.");

var captureGroupResult = result.Groups["cost"];
```

captureGroupResult should contain {get this value} then just add up your values.